# XPCOM C++: Does it support RegExps?

Tags: c++, regex, xpcom

I'm developing a XPCOM C++ component that have to use some RegExps functions

Does XPCOM C++ have build-in support for RegExps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was planned for Firefox 1.0 but after a [long thread there was a decision](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106590) not to add it to core XPCOM.

Answer (score 0):

It is in theory possible to use the regexp support in the JS API but I'm no JSAPI hacker ;-)